# Strange permission issue on Windows 7

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, file-permissions, roaming-profile, folder-redirection

To setup the scene, I have one of my users for whom roaming profile is enabled as well as folder redirection. My issue is that the user cannot open some files in the redirected folders (AppData, Desktop & Documents) for reading.

It's possible to create a file and save it but impossible to open it again or even write in it again once it is created.

[image: Notepad access denied]

This happens only with some files and newly created one. When I look at the file defined and effective permissions, everything is all right.

[image: Defined permissions] [image: Effective permissions]

And to conclude this seems to be related to my user's computer. I logged him on another computer with the same configuration and it worked fine until the first caching.

The only enabled policies are redirected folders and offline files cache encryption.

Thinking of a problem with the user's profile, I removed both local and remote folders with no effects.

Now I have no idea how to solve this issue.

For your information, a Windows Server 2003 is running the Active Directory service while the files are stored on a Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I realized that my problem was related to one of the enabled policy group: offline cache encryption.

I disabled this and [cleared the cache](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/230738). I'll try to configure things correctly as explained in this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/429118/offline-files-access-denied).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying that this will work, but have you gone in and removed the user's profile from the computer completely in *Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Advanced (tab) > User Profiles > [Settings...]* ?

When I was having inexplicable login issues on a couple computers, I ended up tracing the issue back to the profile information (not just the App Data folder) stored on the computer.

After using the GUI to remove this user, you should also check in the registry under *HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\ProfileList* and make sure that the user doesn't have still have an entry here (each subfolder of this location contains a variety of keys, one of which is a username, which you can use to identify to whom the entry belongs).

If it is truly related the state of that user's profile on that computer this should completely wipe out said profile.